# PHP Loop within a loop after x do x

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

Searching on SO for a quick solution to this. I am trying create a loop break after 5 items for example. PHP is not my strongest subject and the developer has left no comments.

The code should output this block, and loop. So there is a loop for the first LI and then a block loop for the 5 items inside it. I can't figure it out.

```
<li class="royalSlide">
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
</li>
```

The code I have edited so far, I added the integer.

```
$i=5;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{       
    $pid=$row["stock_products_code"];
    $dir = "assets/sale/".$pid."/";$dh = opendir($dir);
    echo '<li class="royalSlide">'; 
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {       
        $vpxd=$file;
            if($vpxd=="." || $vpxd=="..")
            {

            }else{
                $vpxd=str_replace(".jpg","", $vpxd);
                echo '<a href="/product-sale.php?prodref='.$vpxd.'" target="_top"><img src="/assets/sale/'.$pid.'/'.$file.'" border="0"  /></a>';
                $i++;
            }       
        }
    echo '</li>';   
closedir($dh);
}
```

Comment: Once $i == 5 you can execute a break; which will 'break' out of the while loop (inner first). Another break would break out of the containing while loop.

Comment: This is my full code without the SQL logins. http://codepad.viper-7.com/3cdSZr

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for the [break statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{    
  $i = 0;

  $pid = $row["stock_products_code"];
  $dir = "assets/sale/$pid/";
  $dh = opendir($dir);

  echo '<li class="royalSlide">'; 

  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
  {       
    $vpxd = $file;

    if($vpxd != "." && $vpxd != ".." )
    {
      $vpxd=str_replace(".jpg","", $vpxd);
      echo '<a href="/product-sale.php?prodref=$vpxd" target="_top"><img src="/assets/sale/$pid/$file" border="0" /></a>';
      $i++;
    }

    if ($i == 5) 
    {
      break; // leave the inner while loop
    }

  }

  echo '</li>';   

  closedir($dh);
}
```

Comment: this does not work, there should be MANY LI and each LI has 5 ANCHORS inside them. This does one LI one link, one LI one link..

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reset the counter. Changed your code on the fly :-)

Comment: Is something to do with my PHP 4 or PHP 5?

Comment: You need to understand the basics of loops, variables and breaks. However ... http://codepad.viper-7.com/cdnZwt could work (can't test it)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this:

```
$i = 5;
```

Set `$i` to zero before each inner loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
    $i = 0;
```

And then abort the inner loop if `$i` hits 5:

```
echo '<a href="/product-sale.php?prodref='.$vpxd. ...
if (++$i == 5) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading that right, you want to have multiple `<ul>` with at most 5 `<li>` each?

```
$i = 0;
while(...) {
   if (($i % 5) == 0) {
      echo '<ul>';
   }
   .... stuff ...
   if ((($i + 1) % 5) == 0) {
      echo '</ul>';
   }
   $i++;
}
```

The first if() will open a new list anytime you've reached a multiple of '5' on the $i counter. So for the i=0, you get a UL. Then it simply outputs individual `<li>` elements and increments $i until it reaches 4. At that point you've output 5 li elements, and it'll now output a `</ul>` to close the list.

Comment: No, sorry if I was not clear. I want MANY LIs with 5 Anchors inside each LI.. so basically I want to make ONE LI and insert 5 links inside each and loop until..